# How do I convert a bitmask to a byte array in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a short integer I want to represent as a bit mask.

How would I take that value and convert it to a bit mask in a byte array of size 2?

For example, say I have the short int value of 3. I want that to be represented as the binary "100" (third bit position is set giving an actual decimal value of "4") and I want that to be represented in a two byte array.

So another example would be a value of "12". In binary, this would be "100000000000" (12'th bit position set) for a decimal value of 2048. In a two byte array this would mean that the first (high order) byte would be "1000" and the second byte (low order) would be "00000000" (0).

Is there a simple way without writing a bunch of convoluted code to take the short int value, convert it to to the bit mask with the short int value bit set, and then storing the resulting value as a two byte array?

Answer (score 2):

It should be simple:

```
    Dim bytes As Byte()
    ReDim bytes(1)

    Dim x As Integer = 12

    x = x - 1
    If x > 0 Then
        If x > 8 Then
            bytes(1) = 1 << (x - 8)
        Else
            bytes(0) = 1 << x
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: This will definitely work.  I just thought there was some even more straight forward way of doing this of which I was unaware.

Comment: I think that this is about as straightforward as you are going to get owing to the somewhat uncommon nature of this operation (having a value define the position of the bit to turn on rather than the more common convert a number to a bit mask operation).